# Which is more secure to pass the Object ID as a hidden field in the form or to pass it in the request itself

Tags: model-binding

i have the following edit view which contains a hidden field which contains the object ID:-

```
@model Elearning.Models.Class

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    }
@section scripts{
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/WordCount.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
<h2>Edit123</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Class</legend>

  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClassID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagedBy)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ManagedBy, new { value = "FL", disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagedBy)
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Timestamp)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Class List", "Index")
</div>
```

this view will be rendered using the following link:-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClassID })
```

my edit action method signature look as the following which will not use the hidden field value:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection colletion)
        {              
            Class c = elearningrepository.GetClass(id);
           //code does here
```

i can also write the action method as follow which accept the value of the hidden field:-

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int ClassID, FormCollection colletion)
        {              
            Class c = elearningrepository.GetClass(Classid);
           //code does here
```

so which apprach is more secure (if any ) passing the object ID as a hidden field OR passing it from the `Html.ActionLink` ?
BR

**Edit:-**
i am checking if the user who will edit the object is `IsManagedBy(User.Identity.Name)` before updating the object as follow:-

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection colletion)
        {

            Class c = elearningrepository.GetClass(id);
           if (!c.IsManagedBy(User.Identity.Name))
            {
                return View("Error");
           }
            try
            {
                if (TryUpdateModel(c))
                {
                   // elearningrepository.setmod(c);
                    elearningrepository.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = c.ClassID });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The hidden field will get rendered into the body of the POST request.  POST bodies are encrypted with SSL.

I am unsure if the path passed via GET is encrypted when using SSL.  Something to look into.

Of course, if you are not using SSL, then neither method is more secure than the other.

Answer (score 1):

It's a trick question. Neither solution offers any security at all. If you're not validating the ids on the server you have a gaping hole no matter which technique you use.

Comment: what kind of "gaping hole" the application will suffer if i am not validating the ID? and what kind of validation i can perform to validate the ID at the server (there is nothing to validate against)?

Comment: @john, usually when you have an ID the current user should only be able to view the page for *that specific id*.  If they can change it (and they can change it using either technique you try to use) then they can change it to some ID for which they should not have access, potentially viewing (and even editing!) data that they should not have access to.  That is the security hole.

Comment: i am checking if the user who will edit the object is IsManagedBy(User.Identity.Name) before updating the object as displayed in my above post.

Comment: @john, then that's great.  That's what I meant by "on the server."  That is secure -- so what are your concerns in asking this question?  What precisely makes you think either choice has an impact on security?